# Comparing md5.Sum to text from file

Tags: go

In learning golang, I wrote a small CLI utility that will take paths as arguments and list out their md5 hash as hex strings. Included are two flags that alter functionality, `--check | -c` which takes an additional file, hashes both, and returns whether or not they match (and exits with the proper return code), and `--text | -t` that takes the path to a text file that is presumed to have exactly the contents of the hexified MD5 sum and checks it (as above).

[The repository is here](https://github.com/Darimart/md5) and code is below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/md5"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var checkSum, textFile string

// build Flags
func init() {
    const (
        checkSumDefault = ""
        checkSumUsage   = "File to check against"
        textFileDefault = ""
        textFileUsage   = "File that has the md5 hash as its only content"
    )

    flag.StringVar(&checkSum, "check", checkSumDefault, checkSumUsage)
    flag.StringVar(&checkSum, "c", checkSumDefault, checkSumUsage)
    flag.StringVar(&textFile, "text", textFileDefault, textFileUsage)
    flag.StringVar(&textFile, "t", textFileDefault, textFileUsage)
}

func makeHash(fname string) [16]byte {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to read file %s", fname))
    }
    return md5.Sum(data)
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    var result int

    if checkSum != "" {
        // check mode -- against file
        checkSumHash := makeHash(checkSum)
        argHash := makeHash(flag.Arg(0))
        if checkSumHash == argHash {
            fmt.Print("They match!")
            result = 0
        } else {
            fmt.Print("No match")
            result = 1
        }
    } else if textFile != "" {
        // check mode -- against text

        checkSum, err := ioutil.ReadFile(textFile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            log.Fatalf("Can't read text file %s", textFile)
        }
        checkSum = bytes.TrimSpace(checkSum)
        argHash := makeHash(flag.Arg(0))
        if strings.EqualFold(fmt.Sprintf("%x", argHash), string(checkSum)) {
            fmt.Print("They match!")
            result = 0
        } else {
            fmt.Print("No match")
            result = 1
        }
    } else {
        // print mode
        for _, fname := range flag.Args() {
            hash := makeHash(fname)
            fmt.Printf("%x\n", hash)
        }
        result = 0
    }
    os.Exit(result)
}
```

I feel like I should refactor out the different functions and have each one return its success code. That's something I'll do when I have a little time free to poke at it.

The biggest question, however, is the best way to compare the `[16]byte` argHash to the `[]byte` checkSum if `--text` is specified. Currently I'm using `bytes.TrimSpace`, casting to `string`,  and comparing that with `Sprintf("%x", argHash)`. Is there a better way? Seems silly to convert both to string rather than comparing bytes, but I don't know a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To clearly state our problem/task:** We want to compare 2 checksums, one supplied as a text being the hexadecimal representation, and the other being an array of the "raw" bytes.

2 forms exist: a *hexadecimal representation* and *raw bytes*. To compare them, we need the same representation. So 2 possible paths:

## 1. Convert the second to hex representation

Let's see your proposed solution. If we want to handle leading/trailing spaces, and if the text input may contain lowercased and uppercased hex digits, your solution is as simple as it can be.

A variation may be to convert the text to lowercased, and then we can simply compare strings without `strings.EqualFold()`. The lowercase conversion can be done by calling [`strings.ToLower()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToLower) or since we already have the input as `[]byte`, by [`bytes.ToLower()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#ToLower):

```
checkSum = bytes.ToLower(bytes.TrimSpace(checkSum))
argHash := makeHash(flag.Arg(0))
if fmt.Sprintf("%x", argHash) == string(checkSum) {
    // They match
} else {
    // They don't match
}
```

## 2. Convert the first to raw bytes

#### Compare slices (`[]byte`)

We may choose to convert the text checksum back to a `[]byte` which holds the *raw* bytes of the checksum (NOT the bytes of the UTF-8 encoded hex representation).

We can parse the hex representation simply with [`hex.DecodeString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#DecodeString). Or even better: since we have the text checksum as a `[]byte`, we can use [`hex.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#Decode) which takes input as a `[]byte`.

As an extra gain, we don't even have to care about lower or upper case: `hex.Decode()` handles that for us.

And we can convert `[16]byte` to `[]byte` by simply slicing it. Once we have 2 `[]byte`, we can use [`bytes.Equal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Equal) to compare them (in Go slices are not comparable unlike arrays).

```
checkSum = bytes.TrimSpace(checkSum)
dst := make([]byte, 16)
if _, err := hex.Decode(dst, checkSum); err != nil {
    // Invalid input, not hex string or not 16 bytes!
} else {
    argHash := makeHash(flag.Arg(0))
    if bytes.Equal(argHash[:], dst) {
        // They match
    } else {
        // They don't match
    }
}
```

#### Compare arrays (`[16]byte`)

As a variation of the previous solution, we will use arrays to do the comparison as arrays are comparable.

Since `makeHash()` already returns an array `[16]byte`, we only need to get the raw bytes of the text checksum into an array. The simplest and fastest is to create an array `[16]byte`, and pass such a slice to `hex.Decode()` that shares its backing array with our new array. We can obtain such a slice by simply slicing the array:

```
checkSum = bytes.TrimSpace(checkSum)
dst := [16]byte{}
if _, err := hex.Decode(dst[:], checkSum); err != nil {
    // Invalid input, not hex string or not 16 bytes!
} else {
    if makeHash(flag.Arg(0)) == dst) {
        // They match
    } else {
        // They don't match
    }
}
```

#### Compare manually (byte-by-byte)

We can also do the comparison manually, it's relatively easy and straightforward.

But first to do it manually, let's create a simple helper function which tells if a hex digit (the text representation) equals to the raw data:

```
func match(hex, raw byte) bool {
    if raw < 10 {
        return hex-'0' == raw
    }
    return hex-'a'+10 == raw || hex-'A'+10 == raw
}
```

And with this the solution:

```
checkSum = bytes.TrimSpace(checkSum)
argHash := makeHash(flag.Arg(0))
if len(checkSum) != 2*len(argHash) {
    // Quick check: length differ, they don't match!
} else {
    equal := true
    for i, v := range argHash {
        if !match(checkSum[i*2], v >> 4) || !match(checkSum[i*2+1], v & 0x0f) {
            equal = false
            break
        }
    }
    // Now the variable "equal" tells if they are equal
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response! I don't have the time to absorb all your suggestions just yet and the details of arrays vs slices are still hazy to me, coming from Python, so it takes a little longer to ponder. I'll dig into this tomorrow and leave a more pointed comment! :)

Comment: @AdamSmith Ok, sure. I also added another solution: "Compare manually".